# Errors when creating OneNote document using SPD workflow

Tags: 2013, content-type, designer-workflow, document-template

In our SP 2013 online environment we have the following situation:

There is a document library that contains multiple content types (e.g. 'MG Document'). these content types are child types of 'Document' and should use an OneNote Template. I tried to use "Folder" as parent instead because it is used for ON files but it is only usable for simple file folders and not for OneNote files as far as I can see.
A Sharepoint Designer (Site-)Workflow should initially create multiple ON notebooks with the template the content type is related to.

We are able to create new notebooks manually with MG Document content type. When executing the SPD Workflow a notebook file is created, too. BUT I can not open this file.

The following messages appear:
"Onenote cannot open the requested package file. The file may be corrupted or may contain no OneNote sections"
"We couldn't open that location. It might not exist or you might not have permission to open it"

In the beginning I guessed there would be an error with the template file but we recognized that the same problem occurs with the "Document" content type and its default template.

Does anyone have an idea how I can set up my (custom) content types in a way that allows me to create OneNote files with an SPD workflows?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to create OneNote documents without issues using Sharepoint 2010 workflows instead of Sharepoint 2013 Workflows. The error only occurs when a SP2013 WF creates a document with custom content type and the associated template. The same functionality (the 'Create Item' command to be precisely) works in SP2010 Workflows.

Comment: And HOW did you solve it?

Comment: As I have already said I used Sharepoint 2010 Workflows instead of Sharepoint 2013 Workflows. The error only occurs when a SP2013 WF creates a document with custom content type and the associated template. The same functionality (the 'Create Item' command to be precisely) works in SP2010 Workflows.

Comment: Great! I've added this to your answer and removed the post notice. Thanks!